# Why are there no basic qualifications for a prime minister or any minister post in India?

Tags: india, election-requirements

For any job, there are certain qualifications and requirements the candidate shall furnish, but the same is not true for ministers or politicians.

Why are there no basic qualifications for a prime minister or any ministerial post in India?

To some extent, while the constitution was framed taking into account the literacy rate in India, it would have been constituted in such a way that anybody could become a minister.

Comment: According to [this question and its answers](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/815/is-setting-a-low-bar-on-qualifications-for-elected-office-similar-around-the-w) this lack of requirements is pretty universal, at least among democracies.

Comment: See also [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/80302/eligibility-criteria-to-become-the-prime-minister-of-india-and-what-is-office-o) which outlines the requirements that do exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eligibility criteria to become the prime minister of India and what is "office of profit"?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/80302/eligibility-criteria-to-become-the-prime-minister-of-india-and-what-is-office-o)

Comment: Unfortunately not, they are similar but not answering my questions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is setting a "low bar" on qualifications for elected office similar around the world?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/815/is-setting-a-low-bar-on-qualifications-for-elected-office-similar-around-the-w)

Answer (score 7):

There is a "basic qualification" and that is you must be a member of the Lok Sabha.  This is a pretty steep requirement.  It is not like anyone can just choose to be a Minister and immediately get the job!

The purpose of job requirements for (eg) a job in an office is just to simplify the hiring process "We know that we want someone who can program and speak English, so we say you must have these qualifications".  But for exceptional jobs there is often no "requirement" beyond convincing the selection committee that you are the best person for the job. And they will look at all the evidence.  A candidate may not have a school certificate, but their life history shows that they are far better candidate. So why put artificial requirements?

In the case of a Minister, you must convince thousands of people to vote for you and then convince the Prime Minister that you are the best person to run a ministry.  In the case of the Prime Minister you must convince millions of people to pick you as the leader of the party, and then convince hundreds of millions of people to vote for your party.

The idea that you must also have a school certificate is, frankly, ludicrous.

Comment: It is also worth noting that having fewer requirements for high public office furthers the separation of powers between the judiciary and the legislature, because the fewer requirements there are, the less room there is for litigation over those requirements. In the U.S., some elected offices that call for the official to personally carry out some licensed profession for the government (county attorney, surveyor, engineer, medical examiner, sheriff, etc.)  and do have job requirements, typically licensure in the relevant profession. But Ministers and the PM just tell other people to do stuff.

Comment: To become member of loksabha, it is only required to be of age greater than 25. How is this even a qualification?

Comment: Nonsence .  You must be over 25 *and win an election*.  Being over 25 is easy enough. Winning the election is a lot harder.

Answer (score -4):

Logic is that if the people still wants the candidate X, despite he is illiterate, then no law should forbid him from being elected. That is the logic of the law.

Similar problem is that why can illiterate people vote. Or people not paying any tax in their entire life - on their own fault - why can still vote.

Many countries normally dislike this western logic, and the western model democracy with it, on this and on many similar reasons.

Comment: One has to have a very particular perspective to declare India's democracy to be "Western," and [literacy tests](https://history.iowa.gov/history/education/educator-resources/primary-source-sets/right-to-vote-suffrage-women-african/voter-registration-literacy) to be foreign to "the West."